# Abstract algebra hw check?

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics

Which properties (reflexive, symmetric, transitive) does the givien relation have?

b) A⊆B on the set of all subsets of a set S

my answer: Reflexive and Transitive.

Reflexive since A⊆A is true

Transitive if A⊆B and B⊆C then A⊆C  is true

d) (-1)^a=(-1)^b on the set Z of integers

My answer: Reflexive, Symmetric, and Transitive

Reflexive since (-1)^a=(-1)^a  is true

Symmetric since If (-1)^a=(-1)^b then (-1)^b=(-1)^a is true

Transitive since If (-1)^a=(-1)^b and (-1)^b=(-1)^c, then (-1)^a=(-1)^b is true

Do my answers seem correct?  I am not entirely sure if that is all I need to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All looks correct, although you prove very little in part $a$. Presumably, you should use the definition of $\subseteq$ somewhere, even if it is intuitively obvious.

You could say for part $b$ that it is equivalent to congruence $\mod 2$ if you are familiar with this language.